# Angular 2 input value not updated after reset

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a simple input that I want to reset the value to empty string after I am adding hero. The problem is the value is not updated. why?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <input type="text" [value]="name" #heroname />
      <button (click)="addHero(heroname.value)">Add Hero!</button> 

      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">          
          {{ hero.name }}        
        </li>
      </ul>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name: string = '';
  heroes = [];

  addHero(name: string) {
   this.heroes.push({name});
   // After this code runs I expected the input to be empty
   this.name = '';
  } 

}
```

Comment: Why push({name}), and not just push(name), push({name: name})?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have one-way binding so when you're typing something in your input your `name` property isn't changed. It remains `""`. After clicking on `Add hero!` button you doesn't change it.

```
 addHero(name: string) {
   this.heroes.push({name}); // this.name at this line equals ''
   this.name = ''; // it doesn't do any effect
 }
```

Angular2 will update `value` property only if it is changed.

[image]

Use two-way binding which is provided by `@angular/forms`

```
[(ngModel)]="name"
```

to ensure that your `name` property will be changed after typing.

Another way is manually implementing changing

```
[value]="name" (change)="name = $event.target.value"
```

Comment: But I'm changing it in the addHero function. this.name = '';

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not understand the comment.

Comment: If the [value] property is bound to the name in my component, when I changing the name I expect the value to be change also.

Comment: Are you saying you want this to output nothing           {{ hero.name }}        ?? or are you saying you want that to say the hero name but nothing to show in the input field?

Comment: Can u share please how u get to this code when debugging? (the code in your image)

Answer (score 0):

In Angular `Template binding works with properties and events, not attributes.` as per [html attribute vs dom property documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#html-attribute-vs-dom-property) of angular so as you have used `[value]` binding its binding to `attributes` not to the `property` of that input and because of it value remain in it after you set `this.name = ""`.

Comment: It's property binding

Comment: From the article that ranakrunal9 mentions: `Attributes initialize DOM properties and then they are done. Property values can change; attribute values can't.`