# Manually set angular <input> value back to the [value] property after typing some text

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection, angular-input

I have a component where I can select an item from a list. There is another section on the screen where the data of that item is shown on the screen. In this data display section, there I have something along the lines of
`<input [value]="profile.name" (change)=updateProfileName(selectedProfile.id, $event)>`
The user can type into the input field to change it. But if they click another tab before the change is registered
Two of the profiles in the list have the same name so when I select one from the other, the angular change detection does not think that the values are different. But when I select the new value, I want the form to reset back to all the unchanged values.

How can I acheive this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41219146/angular-2-input-value-not-updated-after-reset?rq=4

Comment: Basically, change the ``[value]="profile.name"´´ with ``[(ngModel)]="profile.name"´´